# Is there any way to run Asynk task till two minutes in interval of 15 seconds?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-timer

I need to run asynk task till two minutes in interval of every fiften seconds . Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Try using timerTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
void TimerTask(int count)
    {
        if(count>8) // 8 cyclses,because 60*2/15
            return;

        Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Create timer
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run your async task there

                TimerTask(count++); //OnExecute

            }
        }, 0L, 15L * 1000);//every 15 sec (0L - seconds waiting for start)
    }
```

`
    Call it - TimerTask(0);

Comment: another 1 timer mean ? guys please give me details

Comment: i need to modify small thing if i got status '00' till 2 minuts i need to escape out from time , how to do this ?